# pagerank in igraph with isolated node

Tags: r, igraph, pagerank

I wonder how the page_rank() in R's igraph package workes when there are isolated nodes. For example,

```
g <- graph(edges=c(1,2), n = 3, directed = F)
page_rank(g, algo = "prpack")
```

I got (with default damping factor being 0.85.)

```
$vector
[1] 0.46511628 0.46511628 0.06976744
```

Why is this result? I thought node 3 should be `0.15 / 3`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think i figured out the reason. Using the standard page rank algorithm (see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank)), I get `(1/3, 1/3, 1/20)`. Normalize it to a distribution, I get `(0.46511628 0.46511628 0.06976744)`.